# "Product" vs "production"

Tags: word-choice

When developing software, we have servers for development and servers for real customers.

For the real servers environment, should I call it *product environment* or *production environment*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A product is something that is produced. The act of producing something is called *production*.

Your servers that server your customers are producing your product for your customers so they are *production servers* thus the environment they are in is the *production environment*.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Wikipedia: [Production environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_environment)

Answer (score 0):

Production Environment, ofcourse!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you want to agree with an existing answer, simply use the adjacent arrows to upvote them, rather than submitting a new one. If believe those answers are inadequate and want to submit your own, you should explain *why* your answer is what it is, including any appropriate citations. The [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) offers additional guidance on how to use this site.